# Сжатие изображения до определенного размера PHP

Tags: php

Нужно сделать сжатие изображений до определенного размера. В будущем будет стоять в кроне автозапуск скрипта, который будет сжимать изображения в определенной директории. Сейчас есть следующий код:

```
$config = parse_ini_file("config.ini");
$files = glob($config["directory"] . "*.jpg");
$fil = glob($config["directory"] . "*.png");
$files = array_merge($files, $fil);
foreach ($files as $value) {
    $info = getimagesize($value);
    $fsz = filesize($value);
    if ($fsz <= $config["filesize"] * 1024) {
        continue;
    }
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($value);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($value);
    }
    if (isset($image)) {
        $fname = explode("/", $value);
        $filename = $config["out_directory"] . end($fname);
        imagejpeg($image, $filename, 40);
    }
}
```

Сейчас скрипт просматривает все изображения в директории и сжимает их, если они весят больше N килобайт. 
Например, файл изначальным весом в 4.81 Мб удалось сжать максимум до 707 Кб.
Как сделать сжатие до конкретного размера?

Comment: уменьшить ШхВ, сделать черно-белым, ну или иным способом уменьшить количество цветов.

Comment: @teran нужно сохранить исходное изображение. Как видно из скрипта, у меня изображение просто сжимается. Нужно просто сжимать, пока оно не будет определенного размера

Comment: я вижу, но надо понимать, что бесконечно большое (в разрешении) изображение нельзя сжать в 1байт. Придется жертвовать разрешением или цветностью в каком-то виде.